# Can annotation based Transaction manager persist data as on jsp

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-transactions

I am new to Transaction Management with Spring 3. I referred some resources from Google and I understood why and how to use it in application, but I want to know if Transactional method throws error can it help to persist data on jsp page as it was during jsp submission?

Comment: Can you please provide your code? Is your transaction method throwing an error after submission of a form on a JSP?